# How to fix "Cannot find symbol error" in related subproject while running gradle compileJava

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I try to create a spring boot project with gradle using subprojects for different layers (web, business, dataAccess, common).

I followed the instruction of the official gradle guide [Creating Multi-Projects builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/).

Both subprojects are create originally with [Spring.io](http://start.spring.io).

**Problem**

I try to use my `User` class of the subproject *common* in my other subproject *dataAccess*. The import works fine in Intellij. However, when I run `gradlew :dataAccess:compileJava` the task fails because `User` cannot be found:

> Task :dataAccess:compileJava FAILED
>   ...\dataAccess\src\main\java\ch\wprogLK\MyProject\backend\dataAccess\MyProjectDataApplication.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
>           User u = new User();
>           ^
>     symbol:   class User
>     location: class MyProjectDataApplication)

The *common* project gets compiled before the *dataAccess* project. I guess it's a gradle configuration problem that the *dataAccess* project does not know anything about the *common* project at compilation time (maybe a classpath issue?). I'm glad for any help. Thanks.

**Project setup**

- **MyProject**

  - **common**

    - src/main/java/ch/wprogLK/myProject/backend/common/entities

      - User.java
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
  - **dataAccess**

    - src/main/java/ch/wprogLK/myProject/backend/dataAccess

      - AcLuDataApplication.java
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle

**Code**

**MyProject**/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'ch.wprogLK'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java' 
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

**MyProject**/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'

include 'common'
include 'dataAccess'
```

MyProject/**common**/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'ch.wprogLK'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}
```

MyProject/**common**/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'common'
```

MyProject/**common**/src/main/java/ch/wprogLK/myProject/backend/common/entities/User.java

```
package ch.wprogLK.myProject.backend.common.entities;
public class User
{
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
}
```

MyProject/**dataAccess**/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'ch.wprogLK'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":common")
}
```

MyProject/**dataAccess**/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'dataAccess'
```

MyProject/**dataAccess**/src/main/java/ch/wprogLK/myProject/backend/dataAccess/MyProjectDataApplication.java

```
package ch.wprogLK.myProject.backend.dataAccess;
import ch.wprogLK.myProject.backend.common.entities.User;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProjectDataApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProjectDataApplication.class, args);
    }

    public MyProjectDataApplication()
    {
        User u = new User(); //This line is the problem when running gradle :dataAccess:javaCompile
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you compile `a subproject` individually or the entire project?

Comment: @JonathanJohx: I run `gradlew :dataAccess:compileJava` which then compiles the other subprojects as well. For example it runs first `:common:compileJava`. Then when gradle actually tries to compile the subproject dataAccess it fails.
I tried as well running first `gradlew :common:javaCompile`which works fine and the running `gradlew :dataAccess:javaCompile`with still the same problem as before.
When I run `gradlew :javaCompile --info` it's sucessful but with the message "Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date."

Comment: Okay then when you do run from root of project, you need to follow some settings for `common` library, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is missing to set two configurations in order to indicate that `common` is a library. So add the following configuration and `compile`, `run` from root of project.

`common build.gradle`

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Been looking for this quite some time :)

Comment: Great! anything you can ask me on my profile, kind regards. @MrA